# link to node field on another content type

Tags: nodes, files

I have a field that uploads a pdf, I want to get the uri in another node and content type to create a link.

Is this possible to do without knowing the id of the node (so not using node_load) but by the field name? I tried to create an existing field in my node (see screen) but this seemed to just provide a duplicate field without the already uploaded pdf.

The idea is have the users upload the file in one place.

Comment: No - if you want to get access to a value in a field that's attached to an entity (node), you need to know the entity's ID, or at least be able to distinguish it in some other way so that you can query it from the database

Comment: How do you imagine it? Field name only is identical across all nodes of particular content type, so how would you like to identify particular node without it's identification?

Comment: by a unique field name?

Comment: @welovedesign names of fields are not unique, are common per content type. Unless you meant something else by this term?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using the [Linkit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) which has access to managed files.